# how to write splunk query for xml

Tags: splunk

```
<!DOCTYPE EmployeeInventory SYSTEM 'EmployeeInventory.dtd'><EmployeeInventory version="2.0"><ProductInventoryInfo><Product>7781105882846</Product><EmployeeID>12151</EmployeeID><Quantity>28</Quantity><CenterID>167551</CenterID></ProductInventoryInfo></EmployeeInventory>

    <!DOCTYPE EmployeeInventory SYSTEM 'EmployeeInventory.dtd'><EmployeeInventory version="2.0"><ProductInventoryInfo><Product>1781305782846</Product><EmployeeID>12152</EmployeeID><Quantity>18</Quantity><CenterID>167552</CenterID></ProductInventoryInfo></EmployeeInventory>
```

How to write splunk query from above splunk log which will fetch table like this .

```
Product         EmployeeID      Quantity   CenterID
7781105882846   12151               28      167551
1781305782846   12152               18      167552
```

Answer (score 1):

It would help to know what you've tried so far and how those attempts failed to meet your needs.

The trick is extracting fields from the XML.  You could use a series of `rex` commands, but `spath` is simpler.

````
| makeresults
| eval data="<!DOCTYPE EmployeeInventory SYSTEM 'EmployeeInventory.dtd'><EmployeeInventory version=\"2.0\"><ProductInventoryInfo><Product>7781105882846</Product><EmployeeID>12151</EmployeeID><Quantity>28</Quantity><CenterID>167551</CenterID></ProductInventoryInfo></EmployeeInventory>;<!DOCTYPE EmployeeInventory SYSTEM 'EmployeeInventory.dtd'><EmployeeInventory version=\"2.0\"><ProductInventoryInfo><Product>1781305782846</Product><EmployeeID>12152</EmployeeID><Quantity>18</Quantity><CenterID>167552</CenterID></ProductInventoryInfo></EmployeeInventory>"
| eval data=split(data,";")
| mvexpand data  
```The above is just for setting up test data```
```Parse the data```
| spath input=data ```Replace "data" with the name of the field containing the data, perhaps "_raw"```
```Simplify the field names```
| rename EmployeeInventory.ProductInventoryInfo.* as *
```Display the data```
| table Product EmployeeID Quantity CenterID
````